# How to add sheets to vba code in a seperate module?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a couple more worksheets after my `master` worksheet in a VBA code. I have a button to initiate the macro which I have the `master` module and the `CreateSheet` module tied to that button.

```
Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Tempo"
End Sub
```

This is what I have in the `CreateSheet` module, the code runs but no sheets are created.

```
Public polerow As XlRowCol
Public MRBook, RDBook As Workbook
Sheets(1).Name = "Make-Ready"
Set MRBook = Worksheets("Make-Ready").Parent
```

This is what I have in the `master` module that produces all my output. I really would prefer to keep my macro to separate modules like this.

Comment: Is your `createsheet()` procedure stored on the same workbook you want the sheets created? Also with the current code only one sheet will be created, later attempts will throw an error.

Comment: @Damian yes it is stored on the same workbook. I have a module for the initial button that goes as follows.. Sub Button1_Click()
    Call ECOECCSV 'macro1
    Call CreateSheet 'macro2
End Sub

Comment: Then it should work... but again, only for the first time until you rename the worksheet `Tempo`

Comment: @Damian better yet, is it possible to add a new sheet in my main code? Sheets(1).Name = "Make-Ready"
Set MRBook = Worksheets("Make-Ready").Parent

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, you can always use the same procedure without the need to change it's code:

```
Sub NewSheet(SheetName As String)

    Dim SheetExists As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        SheetExists = (.Worksheets(SheetName).Name <> "")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If SheetExists = False Then
            .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = SheetName
        Else
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Sheets(SheetName).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Name = SheetName
        End If
    End With

End Sub
'to call the newsheet you can do this
Sub Test()

    NewSheet "Make-Ready"        

End Sub
```